# hexformatted ipaddress range searching

Tags: c, ip-address, binary-search-tree

I am using a text file where two column are there columnA starting range of ipaddress and columnB end range of ipaddress for example ,,

```
1002000 1003fff
1011000 1011fff
1012000 1013fff
1021000 1021fff
1022000 1023fff
1024000 1027fff
1030000 103ffff
1041000 1041fff
1042000 1043fff
1044000 1047fff
1080000 108ffff
```

my searchkey ipaddress is suppose 1021234 so i want to implement binary search for this i have already  stored them in array like inbuf[a] and inbuf[a+1].How to check for 4 files for example abc.txt xyz.txt sww.txt find the ipaddress falling in these files and return the file name.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How did that work? How didn't it work?

Comment: Thanks for reply i have no idea how to do it sir it was asked me in the interview so please guide me i am learning programming now

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct range {
    unsigned start;
    unsigned end;
} Range;

#define MAX_N 256

Range table[MAX_N];

#define range_file "ip_range.txt"
int load_table(void){
    int n = 0;
    unsigned start, end;
    FILE *fp = fopen(range_file, "r");

    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s can't open.", range_file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(2==fscanf(fp, "%x %x", &start, &end)){
        table[n].start = start;
        table[n++].end = end;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return n;
}

int cmp_range(int no, unsigned key){
    if(key < table[no].start)
        return -1;
    else if(key > table[no].end)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int search(unsigned key, int low, int high){
    while(low <= high){
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        int status = cmp_range(mid, key);
        if(status == 0)
            return mid;//find
        else if(status < 0)
            high = mid -1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;//not find
}

int main (void){
    int n = load_table();
    unsigned key = 0x1021234;
    int i = search(key, 0, n-1);

    if(i < 0)
        printf("%x not found in range table.\n", key);
    else {
        printf("%x in ", key);
        printf("%x-%x\n", table[i].start, table[i].end);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks sir please dont mind i am not able to understand can u make it simple sir or please explain me the steps

Comment: @chandu Where is you do not understand the part?

Comment: According to the profile you already have at least one year of experience.

Comment: cmp_range function  is it nessarcy

Comment: @chandu `cmp_range`  to determine the magnitude of the key at the specified position as strcmp.